# WSH VBScript switch workSHEET in already open Excel workBOOK

Tags: excel, vbscript, wsh

Is it possible to switch worksheets within a workbook in a WSH VBScript (referenced by name) and if so, how would I do it?

This will be used in a script that already opens an Excel file. I want to access a worksheets called "Version Control".

The following is how I am opening the workbook:

```
xlsFile = path & "\xml-sitemap.xls"
Set objExcel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.open(xlsFile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it (amended following Ekkehard.Horner's comment)

```
Dim ws
Dim wb

xlsFile = path & "\xml-sitemap.xls"
Set objExcel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.open(xlsFile)
Set wb = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook 'the ActiveWorkbook will refer to the opened workbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Version Control") 'ws is a Worksheet object
```

Answer (score 1):

When automating Excel from VBScript, the global objects provided by Excel to VBA code are missing. So a minimal "work with sheets" script should look like:

```
Option Explicit

Dim sFSpec : sFSpec     = "P:\athto\your.xls"
Dim oExcel : Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oWB    : Set oWB    = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFSpec)
Dim oWS, sWSName

Set oWS = oWB.Worksheets(1)
sWSName = oWS.Name
WScript.Echo 0, sWSName

Set oWS = oWB.Worksheets(2)
WScript.Echo 1, oWS.Name

Set oWS = oWB.Worksheets(sWSName)
WScript.Echo 2, oWS.Name

oExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VBScript, you can return the name of the tab of an Excel spreadsheet with the ".name" extension.

```
Dim excelPath, objExcel, oData, Excel_tab

excelPath = "C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\file.xls"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oData = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelPath)
Excel_tab = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).name
msgbox(Excel_tab)

objExcel.quit
```