# Using the COM for opening Excel, can't select a particular sheet

Tags: c#, excel, testcomplete

I am using the COM to work with Excel 2007. When I use the following code, it opens to the first sheet by default.

```
Excel = Sys.OleObject("Excel.Application");
Delay (3000); // Wait until Excel starts
Excel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbooks.Open("G:\\Documentation\\CalCit Excel Files\\2004 Test Data v3 FINAL_new.xlsx");
```

I need to select different sheets. I tryed using the following code from the DDTdriver code.

```
Excel = Sys.OleObject("Excel.Application");
Delay (3000); // Wait until Excel starts
Excel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbooks.Open("G:\\Documentation\\CalCit Excel Files\\2004 Test Data v3 FINAL_new.xlsx", "sheet2", true);
```

But this does not work. I have tryed many other configs and still get nothing.

Comment: I don't think [workbooks.open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel) has a way to specify a sheet, but after opening it, you can select the right sheet.

Answer (score 0):

**For Excel version 2013 or later :**

According to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-select-worksheets)

this can be done with [Sheets.Select method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.select(v=office.15).aspx) :

```
((Excel.Worksheet)this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).Select();
```

which in the code the selected sheet is `1`

**another method for older versions of Excel :**

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)this.Sheets["Sheet2"];
sheet.Select(Type.Missing);
```

where `Sheet2` is the name of the sheet

Comment: Is there any way to do in Vb Script?

Comment: Sorry but not familiar with VS Script, but this may help [WSH VBScript switch workSHEET in already open Excel workBOOK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083715/wsh-vbscript-switch-worksheet-in-already-open-excel-workbook)

Comment: Thanks For your Support.

Comment: Above code is not working i am sorry, but is it a bug with Excel 2007?

Comment: I've added another method to answer, try it please.